# HDMI not working on intel card ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my ge62vr with GTX 1060, but I have a problem with HDMI output, it is only working if I use Nvidia card in Nvidia X server, if I choose Intel card HDMI won't work. Because Nvidia card has high battery drain so I want use Intel card with HDMI output.

Is there any solution for this?